# How to tell service open in a new tab instead of windows - OSX Safari

Tags: macos, services, safari, automator, translation

In this article there's the solution I was looking for, however, I would like to open in a new tab instead of a new window, how should be the text?

[Google translate client for OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/296421/google-translate-client-for-os-x/296429)

...

on run argv

tell application "Safari"

make new document at end of documents

set URL of document 1 to "http://translate.google.com/#en|es|" & item 1 of argv

end tell

end run

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892622/open-url-in-new-safari-tab-with-applescript) mentions:

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell window 1
        set current tab to (make new tab with properties {URL:"http://www.stackoverflow.com"})
    end tell
end tell
```

in your case I'd change the properties to:

`{URL:"http://translate.google.com/#en/es/" & item 1 of argv}`

(changed the URL build-up, since yours won't work with current Google Translate)